# Проверка кода на code convention

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Есть какие-нибудь утилиты для проверки кода на:

- code convention
- для рефакторинга

Для IDEA? Или ресурс какой-нибудь?

Comment: в IDEA встроен решарпер. он умеет проверять код на ошибки. можно еще SONAR или PVS studio заюзать

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Resharper это отдельный продук для .net.

Comment: Вам нужен дополнительный внешний рефакторинг или вы не знаете, как пользоваться уже [имеющимся в IDE рефакторингом](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/refactoring-source-code.html) и [статическим анализатором](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/code-inspection.html)?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman теперь они встроили его в IDEA, вроде

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рефакторинг IDEA умеет делать из коробки. Для проверки кода на code smells и различные проблемы можно использовать Code Inspection, он так же встроен в IDEA.

Из внешних средств посмотрите на:

- [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/)
- [PMD](https://pmd.github.io/)
- [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/)

Вы можете легко добавить эти утилиты в ваш проект и настроить их запуска каждый раз при сборке.

Если вы планирует использовать Continuous Integration сервер, то стоит настроить использование [Sonarqube](https://www.sonarqube.org/)